# Twitter API: Constantly getting 401 status using Oauth and ruby gem (Timestamp Out of bounds)

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, rubygems

im new to ruby and trying to play a bit with Twitters API. I got my keys from twitter dev site and set their permissions to 'read, write and access direct messages'. I then tried to use some code found on codecademy to retrieve status code but got **401 error** (replaced keys with X). The weird things is that this code in codecademy retrieves 200 status code, so im thinkings is something in my computer:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'

    consumer_key = OAuth::Consumer.new(
        "X",
        "X")
    access_token = OAuth::Token.new(
        "X",
        "X")

    # All requests will be sent to this server.
    baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"

    # The verify credentials endpoint returns a 200 status if
    # the request is signed correctly.
    address = URI("#{baseurl}/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")

    # Set up Net::HTTP to use SSL, which is required by Twitter.
    http = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
```

I also tried using twitters gem (adding of course the needed keys) and this time i get the following error **Timestamp out of bounds (Twitter::Error::Unauthorized)**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end


Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.3p429.

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: where did you get your oauth token from ?

Comment: I got it from https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Answer (score 0):

I have been having your same issues and looking at oauth docs I have found the following:

```
Make a regular GET request using AccessToken:
@response = @token.get('/people')
@response = @token.get('/people', { 'Accept'=>'application/xml' })
```

You will find more details here if you are curious: http://oauth.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/OAuth/AccessToken.html

Anyhow here is my code:

```
def prepare_access_token()

  @opts = {
    'oauth_token' => 'TOKEN',
    'oauth_token_secret' => 'TOKEN_SECRET',
    'api_key' => 'API_KEY',
    'api_secret' => 'API_SECRET'
  }

  consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("#{@opts['api_key']}", "#{@opts['api_secret']}",
                               { :site => "http://api.twitter.com",
                                 :scheme => :header
                               })
  # now create the access token object from passed values
  token_hash = { :oauth_token => "#{@opts['oauth_token']}",
               :oauth_token_secret => "#{@opts['oauth_token_secret']}"
  }
  access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash )
  return access_token

end

#here is your url
call_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"
uri = URI.encode(call_url)
# Exchange our oauth_token and oauth_token secret for the AccessToken instance.
access_token = prepare_access_token()
# use the access token as an agent to get the home timeline
response = access_token.get(uri)
```

This worked for me. If you have feedback feel free to share it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue yesterday, since a couple days ago. What happened was that I lived overseas for a while, and I had my region set up to region X, but had manually changed my clock to my current one. As soon as I set up my current region and sync'd with the internet timezone, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (401) I resolved it by going into the app in twitter and regenerating the consumer key and Consumer Secret, which is very easy as there is a button to do it, using the new values stopped my 401 errors. Hope this helps someone.